# Ember 2.11+ can't find `ember-template-compiler` after removing ember from bower

Tags: ember.js

Since [Ember version 2.11](http://emberjs.com/blog/2017/01/23/ember-2-11-released.html#toc_ember-no-longer-supplied-via-code-bower-code), it should be possible to remove ember from bower, and instead load the library using the npm `ember-source` module.

I've run `npm install --save-dev ember-source`. I've removed `ember` from the `bower.json` file, and run `rm -rf bower_components/ember`.
I've added `ember-source` to `packages.json` and installed it .

When I run `ember serve`, it fails with this message:

```
Cannot find module 'path/to/myapp/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler'
Error: Cannot find module 'path/to/myapp/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.included (path/to/myapp/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile/index.js:48:20)
    at Class.superWrapper [as included] (path/to/myapp/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at EmberApp.<anonymous> (path/to/myapp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:495:15)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at EmberApp._notifyAddonIncluded (path/to/myapp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:490:45)
    at new EmberApp (path/to/myapp/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:140:8)
```

It looks like ember is trying to load `ember-template-compiler` from the bower module, which no longer exists. How can I tell ember that it should instead be looking for `node_modules/ember-source/dist/ember-template-compiler.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating it in package.json

```
 "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.6"
```

Refer https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/6711

Comment: Thanks! My Google-fu failed me.

Comment: [Comparing `v0.3.5` with `v0.3.6`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile/compare/v0.3.5...v0.3.6) of `ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile`, it looks like the crucial change was renaming `ember-core` to `ember-source`.